# VS Code having difficulties importing modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, python-import

Currently I'm trying to import a lot of module for a data science project I'm working on. IBM IDE has put up a roadblock with a computing limit and creating a new account isn't working so I've turned to VS Code to edit my notebook. However, when importing my modules for the work, it comes up like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import re
import json
import requests
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
!pip install folium==0.5.0
import folium
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9352/932018738.py in <module>
----> 1 import pandas as pd
      2 pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
      3 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
      4 from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Would really nice some help with this. I've also installed algorithm and it's had no change on this. Have also installed python 3.9.6 and set it as my interpreter.
By the way, I've very new to all this so please excuse me if I'm less knowledgable or I'm making silly errors :P

Comment: I guess that you install the python extension in VS and you install as well pandas in your python 3.9.6 distribution, isnt it?

Comment: @F. Nielsen Yep did all that. The page says to install python on my system then install the extension and everything should be fine? Maybe that's not for juypeter? i don't really know

Comment: Nowadays when you install python extension in VS you're installing at the same time jupyter. Once you open the _.py_ file, Is VS showing you in the left bottom bar "Python _version you have_"?

Comment: @F.Nielsen It's saying 'Python 3.9.6 64-bit' in the bottom left but I'm not opening a .py file I'm in a .ipynb file.

Comment: If you are trying to run a _.ipynb_ file, can you run a simple block code with `print('Hello world')`? Maybe you need to install some more extensions and in the case that you don't have it VS will recommend you these ones that you need.

On the other hand, sometimes the first time that you run jupyter in VS you need to select the kernel that you want to use (it is showed in the upper right window of the  _.ipynb_ file)